# Why am I getting a bad signature for RSA key error with Rysnc crontab between Linux and macOS?

Tags: linux, ssh, ssh-keys

I'm trying to Rsync backups into another machine on a LAN.  I've copied my key over and even using SSH manually, I get the following error, which keeps my crontabs from connecting:

```
client_global_hostkeys_private_confirm: server gave bad signature for RSA key 0: error in libcrypto
```

I've replaced the entry in `authorized_keys` on the target box, as well as cleared out that box's entry in `known_hosts` and the same thing happens. I can only think that this `signature` is the issue.

Not sure if this is relevant, but the source box is Linux, target box is latest macOS.

How can I fix this so that these crons work properly? I'm not even sure what the problem is. The connection works manually with SSH and Rsync.

Update: Further info. Should be no reason why this isn't working. I'm trying to write to a destination file that does not exist.

```
myTarget='user3@myworkstation.local:/Volumes/Tug/storBackups/server_n_PG_dbname_p33_backups/';
myfile=$myTarget'test_ssh.txt';
echo $myfile
echo "alpha" | ssh user3@myworkstation.local 'cat > $myfile'
```

response:

```
user3@myworkstation.local:/Volumes/Tug/storBackups/server_n_PG_dbname_p33_backups/test_ssh.txt
client_global_hostkeys_private_confirm: server gave bad signature for RSA key 0: error in libcrypto
zsh:1: no such file or directory:
```

`ssh` versions:

```
Source: OpenSSH_8.7p1, OpenSSL 3.0.1 14 Dec 2021
Target: OpenSSH_8.6p1, LibreSSL 3.3.6
```

Comment: Does the Rsync work manually? What about SSH? If you SSH from Linux to macOS does it work? In general, the remote user on the macOS system should have a directory named `.ssh` with permissions of 700 and a file named `.ssh/authorized_keys` with 600 permissions. Copy the contents of the `.ssh/id_rsa.pub` on the Linux system into the `.ssh/authorized_keys` file on the macOS system. Then SSH from Linux to macOS and it should work. Look at [this answer on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67556915/117259) for a tip; it might be a hostname mismatch issue.

Comment: `ssh` works.  `rsync` works manually, and still has that `warning`/`error`.  I pasted more than once (deleted first) using this: `ssh-copy-id -i /home/user1/.ssh/id_rsa.pub user1@workstation.local`.  Did this three times, same error.

Comment: Now `permissions` issues for the `cron`.  I redid all of that and entered that directive into `config`.  `-rw------- 1 user1 staff 1.2K Jul 27 12:37 authorized_keys`.    `Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied, please try again.
Received disconnect from 192.168.1.4 port 22:2: Too many authentication failures` So the script stops at that point.

Comment: Could be a host keys issue and not a public key issue. Hopefully someone else will come across this and assist.

Comment: Would this have anything to do with `known_hosts`?  Or is that outgoing only?

Comment: Yeah. I believe would have to do with `known_hosts` not too clear why.

Comment: Hi, did you ever get this to work?

Comment: Still trying to make things work.  Literally just looked at a log, and it's full of permissions issues.